# Trying to separate the keys of the table into a better format

Tags: sql-server

I have this query which gets me the data for the table

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    mydatabase..systypes t, 
    mydatabase..syscolumns c 
LEFT JOIN 
    mydatabase..sysobjects obj ON c.id = obj.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    mydatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ON obj.NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    mydatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE cu ON c.NAME = cu.COLUMN_NAME 
WHERE 
    obj.id = c.id 
    AND t.xtype = c.xtype 
    AND obj.name = 'mytable' 
    AND obj.xtype = 'U' 
    AND (cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME IS NULL OR cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'PK_%' OR cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'UK_%') 
ORDER BY 
    c.colorder
```

This will be the results as the foreign keys/primary keys/unique keys but it does not point out the composite key.

How can I modify this query to return the proper details for it?

Comment: Why mix ANSI-89 and ANSI-92 `JOIN` syntaxes here? Also, you should really be using the `sys` schema here, rather than the `sys{object type}` objects.

Comment: Terms like "better format" and "proper detail" mean nothing to anyone but you. Provide more detail.

Comment: i am ok to change what works best here, to be noted is i used this very long back and it was working, but now it started messing up all alsong, even it return the resuilts. So all i am trying here is to get results which should correctly show me that this is  composite keys, primary key, foreign keys and so on. so it should not mess up